# Simple macro for converting range of genealogic hierarchy data to list data

Tags: excel, vba, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have data formatted in a CSV as columns of Parents, Children, Grandchildren and so on to the nth column and mth row.

- Each Parent can have several children, ordered as a list in the adjacent column, with the first child in a cell adjacent to its parent, and subsequent children in cells below this one.
- Each Child can have several Grandchildren, ordered in an adjacent column in a like manner, etc.

I'm looking for a Google sheets macro that can output from this range of n columns and m rows a 2-column list of relations between each parent and child, each child and grandchild, and so on, as individual IDs pulled from the ID lookup table.

- Example of desired output:

  ```
  Parent1_ID;Child1_ID        
  Parent1_ID;Child2_ID        
  Parent1_ID;Child3_ID        
  Child1_ID;Grandchild1_ID
  etc.
  ```

Please see sample data google sheet for a more accurate example of current and desired output data:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Y6MvJcAjHlQFl-JukLuXvhDzXup2cCU_QU4bZt6JZrM/edit?usp=sharing

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: does this needs to be a macro or could this be a formula?

Comment: Why would Title m have its own childless entry?

Comment: @player0 it could be a formula.

Comment: @Excelosaurus Title m doesn't have to have an entry if it is childless. Good question

Comment: You used Google Sheets for illustrative purposes, right? ... The 2 proposed answers are for Excel VBA.

Comment: I did use Google Sheets! I forgot to mention a Google sheets macro would be preferable, but I am trying out the VBA macro in Excel. If you guys can provide a Sheets equivalent that'd be incredible.

Comment: In fact, the simplest would be to forget the "ID Lookup Table" Tab, and just output IDs for each string entry, going from 1 to n, where the first string is automatically given ID "1", and each unique string gets its own ID. Of course, duplicate strings would share the same ID.

Answer (score -1):

The general idea would be to look at each child and find its parent by first looking towards the left, then up if none is found.

You could put this sub and function [in a module](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2013/12/06/add-run-vba-macro-excel/):

```
Public Sub DoTheHierarchyThing(ByVal prngSource As Excel.Range, ByVal prngDestinationTopLeftCell As Excel.Range)
    Dim rngChildren As Excel.Range
    Dim rngChild As Excel.Range
    Dim rngParent As Excel.Range

    'Find the children in the source zone, excluding its first column.
    Set rngChildren = prngSource.Resize(prngSource.Rows.Count, prngSource.Columns.Count - 1).Offset(0, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

    'Scan the children.
    'First look on the left for a parent, then up if none is found.
    For Each rngChild In rngChildren.Cells
        Set rngParent = rngChild.Offset(0, -1)
        If IsEmpty(rngParent.Value2) Then
            'Look up.
            Set rngParent = rngParent.End(xlUp)
        End If

        prngDestinationTopLeftCell.Value2 = GetTitleSuffix(rngParent.Value2)
        prngDestinationTopLeftCell.Offset(0, 1).Value2 = GetTitleSuffix(rngChild.Value2)

        Set prngDestinationTopLeftCell = prngDestinationTopLeftCell.Offset(1)
    Next
End Sub

Private Function GetTitleSuffix(ByVal psTitle As String) As String
    GetTitleSuffix = Trim$(Replace(psTitle, "Title ", "", Compare:=vbTextCompare))
End Function
```

where `prngSource` is the range covering your titles, and `prngDestinationTopLeftCell` is the first cell of the destination table.

Then you would, in your own sub or function, call the sub as follows:

```
Public Sub MySub
    'Your code, if any...

    'Call the sub with appropriate parameters:
    DoTheHierarchyThing Sheet1.Range("A1:E53"), Sheet1.Range("A55")

    'Your code, if any...
End Sub
```

Finally, from Excel's View menu, Macros, you'd choose MySub in the list and run it.

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean that I need to replace `prngSource` by whatever sheet and range my data is in? Or should I replace `Excel.Range` by `Sheetx.Range("etc.")`?

Comment: Downvoter, mind to elaborate? @Nicolas, the example I provided shows how to call the sub; you don't have to modify the sub itself, just the way you call it. The example supposes you have your multi-column hierarchy data on Sheet1, cells A1 to C11, and want to start your summary parent-child table on the same sheet, at address G1. Just replace the 2 arguments with ranges that correspond to your situation.

Comment: When I copy paste `DoTheHierarchyThing Sheet1.Range("A1:E53"), Sheet1.Range("A55")` onto your first line of the sub, just after **Public Sub**, I get a Compile error: Expected: end of statement, with *Sheet1* highlighted. I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Edited the answer to make it clearer how to invoke the sub.

Comment: It worked! Thanks!! Is there a way to easily convert this VBA macro for use in Google Sheets? Cheers

Comment: Probably doable, but I can't help on this topic; you could raise a new question, but make sure you try for yourself beforehand or you might get hammered :-D. And the best way to thank me is to upvote/mark as answer ;-)